# Simulate the look of typing, not the actual keypresses, in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I'm trying to write a simple function that will make it appear as though someone is typing in a `textarea`

-- This is my function (forgive me if its atrocious, but I don't normally use javascript) ---
The `console.log()` part works fine, but for some reason I cannot get this script to update the dom the way I would expect...

```
        function type(string) {
            value = "";

            el = document.getElementById("typeArea");
            for (var i = 0; i < string.length; i++) {
                value += string[i];
                //$("#fbw > textarea").val(value);
                el.textContent = value;
                console.log(value);
                sleep(160);
            }
            sleep(2000);
        }
```

I appreciate any insight you can give me.

Comment: Why have you tagged this jQuery if you're not using jQuery?

Comment: What *does* happen? Also, jsfiddle/etc is nice for stuff like this.

Comment: jQuery is an option I am willing to use. In fact, I tried jQuery first. 

Good point, I'll throw in a jsfiddle, momentarily.

Everything works, except for the part in the loop that is supposed to update the contents of the textarea.... even console.log shows each update...

Answer (score 11, accepted):

***[`jsFiddle Demo`](http://jsfiddle.net/uprsd/)***

All you were missing was a construct instead of `Sleep`. The js approach for accomplishing this is to use a timeout and a recursive call in order to iterate through your string

```
function type(string,element){
 (function writer(i){
  if(string.length <= i++){
    element.value = string;
    return;
  }
  element.value = string.substring(0,i);
  if( element.value[element.value.length-1] != " " )element.focus();
  var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * (100)) + 140;
  setTimeout(function(){writer(i);},rand);
 })(0)
}
```

Comment: Ah, this is precisely what I was looking for, and very elegant - !
Thank you, it worked like a charm, and that very much explains why my code was not working.

Comment: The only drawback of this code is that in IE it get the focus for every letter it writes so the page becomes useless. Looking for a solution but at the time not valid for IE.

Comment: Why doesn't this work with `getElementsByClassName` ?

Comment: In what sense were you trying to use getElementsByClassName with this approach?

Answer (score 3):

You can do something like this using setTimeout function.
[**Codepen**](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/thnCd)

```
$(function(){
  simulateTyping('looks  like someone is typing...', '#txt')

  function simulateTyping(str, textAreaId) {
    var textArea = $(textAreaId);

    var currentCharIndex = 0;
    function typeChar(){
      if (currentCharIndex >= str.length)
        return;
      var char = str[currentCharIndex];
      textArea.val(textArea.val() + char);
      currentCharIndex ++;
      setTimeout(typeChar, 500);
    } 

    typeChar();

  }
})
```

Comment: I will try that momentarily, but any idea why the code I already wrote doesn't work?

Comment: Well, you don't have any fiddle or codepen, so it is hard to say.